# Is it possible to get a digital download of the entire US VFR charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a download of every US sectional chart stitched together like what you would find on Skyvector when you press "World VFR"? I tried looking on Skyvector, but couldn't find a download, and I think it would be nearly impossible to stitch together the entire US in Photoshop from the FAA downloads.

Comment: The maps are geo referenced, stitching them together should be easy.

Comment: I don't know if there's a downloadable file but the FAA does provide a ["wall chart" product](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/planningcharts/VFRWall/) which covers the entire contiguous US.